# A limit involving a double sum of products of arctangent values

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, trigonometric-series

How to evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \tan^{-1} \left ( \dfrac{i}{n} \right) \tan^{-1} \left ( \dfrac{j}{n} \right) \right] ?$$

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just have to evaluate two limits through a Riemann-sum argument:
$$ A=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\arctan^2\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\arctan^2(x)\,dx = 0,$$
$$ B=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\arctan\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\arctan(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi-\log(4)}{4}$$
to deduce that:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\arctan\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)=\frac{B^2-A}{2}=\color{red}{\frac{(\pi-2\log 2)^2}{32}}.$$

Comment: Wow...that was great :-D

Comment: +1 Really Great answer. A question, could you please give a proof of how you transformed the sum or just a reference?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif: it is a well-known identity: $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}f(i)f(j)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)^2 \right]$$ that follows by symmetry.

Comment: Ah that's what I was talking about. Thanks ;)

Comment: @jackd'aurizio Forgive me if the medication I'm taking is affecting me, but that "well-known identity" is incorrectly written.  In fact, it would exclude all the diagonal terms, which are not excluded in the original sum.  I believe we need a plus sign rather than a minus sign.  Note herein that the answer is unaffected because $A=0$.  Again, pardon me if my mind is not working well today.

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is a minor issue here, but from $i\color{red}{<}j$ it follows that the diagonal terms *are* excluded from the original sum, so the minus sign should be right.

Comment: Jack, the inequality is $\le$ and so includes the diagonal.  Unless the meds are really reaking havoc.

Comment: @Dr.MV: in such a case, I do not understand to which $\leq$ sign you are referring to. The OP's double sum has $i<j$, as well as my identity above.

Comment: Jack, in both cases I am reading $$\sum_{1\le i\le j \le n}$$.  So, it does seem to include the case for which $i=j$, does it not?

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is probably some sort of rendering issue. I swear there is a strict inequality in both cases :D